# Sub-group and Super-group (Class/Subclass) relation in OWL

Tags: schema, rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs

I need some help regarding OWL syntax. I have a synthetic population class called 'Person'. Person contains population information, and PersonWithinAdminRegion is another class represents subgroup of person class. For example  'Person' class contains information about all persons in the USA.  FloridaPerson or MiamiPerson can be an example of PersonWithinAdminRegion.  Basically,  PersonWithinAdminRegion is a subgroup of supergroup Person. It not sub-class because sub-class inherits properties of super-class and add some more. It is not the case in my situation. My question is how to show sub-group of a super-group in OWL syntax?

```
Person a owl:Class.
PersonWithinAdminRegion ? ?
```

Comment: Are you sure of your modelling perspective? Aren't MiamiPerson and FloridaPerson also Persons (which is an abstraction of all USA people in your context)? Could you please clarify more by giving an example of a property that Person has, but MiamiPerson for example doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

There is no inheritance in OWL.  Therefore no properties are inherited by subclasses.  The subclass hierarchy is a type of subsumption hierarchy with only one semantic: a member of a subclass is a member of the (super) class.  An example:

```
:Person a owl:Class .
:PersonWithinAdminRegion a owl:Class .
:PersonWithinAdminRegion rdfs:subClassOf :Person .
:FloridaPerson a :PersonWithinAdminRegion .
```

From this, one can infer:

```
:FloridaPerson a :Person .
```

And that is all.  No other properties or values will be inferred.  E.g. RDFS and OWL semantics are more like set theory (classification) than object-oriented class definition.

So it seems the above will get you the semantics that you want.  If you wanted to go deeper into the subsumption hierarchy, let's say:

```
:PersonInFloridaRegion rdfs:subClassOf :PersonWithinAdminRegion .
:p1 a :PersonInFloridaRegion .
```

...then you will be able to infer:

```
:p1 a :PersonWithinAdminRegion .
:p1 a :Person .
```

...and so on.

Comment: It's not exactly the question here, but there is a sense in which properties are "inherited" by **super**classes.  E.g., if A is a superclass of B, and the domain of property p is B, then A is also a domain of p.  (Since "the domain of p is B" means that "if p(x,y) then x is a B", and "B is a subclass of A" means "if x is a B, then x is an A", then "p(x,y)" also implies that "x is an A".)  So domains and ranges are "inherited in reverse".

Comment: Still not object-oriented inheritance.  It is just implications of inference in standard RDFS reasoning profiles.  To call it "inheritance" only confuses the matter for those looking for OO behavior.

Comment: Definitely not the same thing.  I only pointed it out because in my experience, it's been one of the more surprising aspects to people when they look at, inferred domains and ranges, precisely because it's the *opposite* of what you get with object-oriented inheritance (at least when people are conflating OWL properties and fields/methods in OO languages).

Comment: @scotthenninger: You mentioned that there is no inheritance in OWL. However in "A Semantic Web Primer for Object-Oriented Software Developers" page (https://www.w3.org/TR/sw-oosd-primer/)  section 3.3 for both object oriented language, OWL & RDF mentioned that "Classes can be arranged in a subclass hierarchy with inheritance." What is the meaning of inheritance in OWL/RDF? How is it different from object oriented language? An example will be helpful to clarify the concept.

Comment: The RDFS/OWL object model is different than oo programming languages.  I would say that "with inheritance" is a misnomer.   Further detail seems like a separate question, but I think the answer and discussion here does a good job of providing examples.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I am still not sure of your modelling perspective, and whether there are some properties that `Person` has, but `PersonWithinAdminRegion`, doesn't. Here is an idea for solution.

You can create a generic class `Person`, and a `subclass` of it `USAPerson`, then a `PersonWithinAdminRegion`, which is a `subclass` of `Persons` as well and a sibling of `PersonWithinAdminRegion`. Thus:

1. Both `USAPerosn` and `PersonWithinAdminRegion` are `Person`;
2. `Persons` will include `USAPersons`, so when make a subset of `Person` you can still have the control over `USAPerosn`;
3. `PersonWithinAdminRegion` can still not have properties that `USAPerson` have.

   ```
   Person a owl:Class
   USAPerson a owl:Class
   PersonWithinAdminRegion a owl:Class

   USAPerson rdfs:subClassOf Peron
   PersonWithinAdminRegion rdfs:subClassOf Peron
   ```

Hope this helps.